# Problems with font encoding in the editor

Tags: texmaker, input-encodings

How can I fix the following problem with a file in TeXmaker?

I did this to my text file(brief example): `�������\\\` 
My text file looks like a bunch of windings. I cannot seem to fix the problem in my file. I opened the file in TeXmaker editor. None of my other files seem to be affected.

Comment: It may be problem of encoding, e.g. windows125x vs. utf8. Please check the setting of editor. And, oh, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)

Comment: I did that It seems to not want to accept the change. Currently the editor is set to utf8.

Comment: Before you do *anything*, make a copy of the file and only experiment with the copy. I guess you mean TeXmaker? Which OS are you using?

Comment: On a Unix-ish system, you can use `file <my file name>.tex` to get information about the file, often including information about the encoding. If you are using a suitable OS, try that and let us know the results. If not, if there's an equivalent for Windows, use that.

Comment: Textmaker is my client and my OS is windows.

Comment: The ‘Tools’  menu has a submenu: ‘Convert to unicode’. Make  a copy of your file for  safety, and try to convert.

Comment: tried it was a no go.

Comment: what is `windows-1252`?